# How to create a "0000001" type number format?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I want to generate **incremental receipt numbers** like this format "00000001". Every time new transaction happen, receipt number should increase by 1.

```
0000001
0000002
0000003

0000010
0000011

0000100
0000101
```

So, how could I implement this type of number format. Is there any special number formats in objective C?

Comment: Generating the number is the "hardest" part. Once you've got the number, formatting it with some zeroes for padding is trivial.

Comment: Keywords here are "nsstring format". That is, the the number being incremented is just an integer. But then it is formatted as a string for display or output.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If your numbers are integers and only the output matters, you can do:

```
NSString * output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%07d", integer];
```

to have the number be formatted with 7 digits, leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

How about just answering the question

```
  NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08d", intvalue];
```

change the 8 to however many leading zeros you want